# Pass string to static image reference in ApplicationAdvice

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an `ApplicationAdvice` class that passes a reference to a profile picture on every page:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationAdvice {
...

@ModelAttribute("currentProfilePicture")
    public String currentProfilePicture(Principal principal, Model model) {

        if (principal != null) {
            String currentProfilePicture = "@{/images/default-profile-picture.png}";
            log.info(currentProfilePicture);
            model.addAttribute("currentProfilePicture", currentProfilePicture);
            return currentProfilePicture;
        } else {
            String currentProfilePicture = "@{/images/default-profile-picture.png}";
            log.info(currentProfilePicture);
            model.addAttribute("currentProfilePicture", currentProfilePicture);
            return currentProfilePicture;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="profilePicture hvr-pulse-grow" th:src="${currentProfilePicture}" />
```

Am I not escaping the static reference properly? `@{/images/default-profile-picture.png}` The url string prints out fine... I basically just want to pass a string to a static file to the img tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this:

`String currentProfilePicture = "/images/default-profile-picture.png";`

`<img class="profilePicture hvr-pulse-grow" th:src="@{${currentProfilePicture}}" />`

You can't pass an entire thymeleaf string to be evaluated without doing some tricks with the preprocessing, but the above should do what you want.